# How to parse through .txt to find hours, and set up a count of each hour

Tags: python, list, dictionary

First of all, here are the requirements for what I'm looking for:

1. Prompt for a file name
2. Opens that file and reads through a text file
3. Displays a custom error message if the file does not exist
4. You can pull the hour out from the 'From ' line by finding the time and then splitting the string a second time using a colon.
   From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan 5 09:14:16 2008
5. Accumulated the counts for each hour (key)
6. Print out the count for each of the hours after the program has completed execution. The counts should be sorted by hour as shown below.

00: 13 times,
01: 17 times,
02: 01 time,
03: 29 times etc.

So far, I covered steps 1-4, yet I'm stuck at part 4 about splitting. I am parsing through a basic txt file, and each line is neat and properly formatted.  Here's what I got so far:

```
try:
     fh = open('mbox.txt')
except IOError:
     print('File cannot be opened. ',fname)
     quit()


for line in fh:
     if not line.startswith('From '):
         continue
else:
    nline = line.rstrip()
    nline = line.split()
    print(nline)
    # nline is now just 'From ' and splits up each word
    # Next, need to select fifth string from nline list
    l = nline[5]
    new = l.split(':')
    new = new[0]
    print(new)
```

The next step from here is using a dictionary and counting each hour as they com e by.
Here's the template for dictionary that my teacher gave out:

```
counts = dict()
print('Enter a line of text:')
line = input('')

words = line.split()

print('Words:', words)

print('Counting...')
for word in words:
     counts[word] = counts.get(word,0) + 1
print('Counts', counts)
```

So my question is: How do I get a list of hours(hh:mm:ss format) to put into the dictionary? Right now, type(new) is str, but I need a list to loop over to collect the hours. I want to add each new variable into a list, but I cant for some reason. I apologize if there is any confusion, additionally please point out if my code could be cleaner and how I could've phrased this question better.

Comment: I'm confused - you want to only get the hour portion of the date, but then you ask _How do I get a list of hours (hh:mm:ss format) to put in the dictionary_? Wouldn't your dictionary look more like, e.g. `{ '00': 1, '01': 3, '02': 4, ... }`? You already have the `hh:mm:ss` format after all your splitting work, and then you have the hour portion after doing a `split(':')`. So now you should just have to combine your code with what your teacher's said given you related to dictionaries and count how many occurrences of each hour there are.

Comment: What about *regex*?

Comment: @birryree, I'm sorry let me clarify. I was just saying that I do need just the hours part from the hh:mm:ss format, but I don't know how to separate the hh part, and put those into a dictionary. However, what you described near the end is what I'm looking for. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2):

I think it'd be good to explain the part of your code you're stuck on so you can see that you were very close to the problem solution.

Basically, we care about the code you did to get the hours portion of every line of text.

```
nline = line.rstrip()
nline = line.split()
print(nline)
# nline is now just 'From ' and splits up each word
# Next, need to select fifth string from nline list
l = nline[5]
new = l.split(':')
new = new[0]
print(new)
```

And here's an example line of text from your question:

```
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan 5 09:14:16 2008
```

I'm doing this in an [`ipython`](https://ipython.org/) session.

```
# Here I define your block of code as its own method
# so we can test it out
In [1]: def process(line):
   ...:     nline = line.rstrip()
   ...:     nline = line.split()
   ...:     print(nline)
   ...:     l = nline[5]
   ...:     new = l.split(':')
   ...:     new = new[0]
   ...:     print(new)
   ...:
```

Now let's feed that example input to it

```
In [2]: process('From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan 5 09:14:16 2008')
Output: ['From', 'stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za', 'Sat', 'Jan', '5', '09:14:16', '2008']
Output: 09
```

So you got to the point where `new` is now the hours part of the time.

What you need to know from this point is that your teacher essentially just gave you the implementation of part 5 - you just need to know how to tweak the code given to achieve the same results in your own code.

Here's an annotation of your teacher's code:

```
# Create an empty dictionary
# an equivalent here is `counts = {}`
counts = dict()

# Not particularly interesting, ask the user to
# type in a string of words
print('Enter a line of text:')
line = input('')

# Split previous input by spaces - this results in a list()
# If input line was... "cat dog cat rabbit fish"
# Output of this would be: ["cat", "dog", "cat", "rabbit", "fish"]
words = line.split()

print('Words:', words)

print('Counting...')

# iterate through each word in the list we got from line.split()
for word in words:
     # This takes advantage of some features of Python's dictionary
     # basically, attempt to get the value associated to counts[word]
     # and if it doesn't exist, return 0. Add 1 to whatever that result it.
     counts[word] = counts.get(word,0) + 1

     # The expanded form of the previous line would like more like this
     # count_of_word = counts.get(word, 0)
     # count_of_word = count_of_word + 1
     # counts[word] = count_of_word
print('Counts', counts)
```

So the part of your teacher's code that really matters to you are the following lines:

```
counts = dict()
# ... stuff here ...
counts[word] = counts.get(word, 0) + 1
```

Now how would you bolt that logic into your own code? You'd declare a `dict` before you start iterating through the lines of your file. And then you use the second line when you have the hours component of each line. Here's an example of how to integrate it into your code.

```
try:
     fh = open('mbox.txt')
except IOError:
     print('File cannot be opened. ',fname)
     quit()

# Create empty dictionary for storing hour counts
counts = dict()

for line in fh:
     if not line.startswith('From '):
         continue
else:
    nline = line.rstrip()
    nline = line.split()
    print(nline)
    # nline is now just 'From ' and splits up each word
    # Next, need to select fifth string from nline list
    l = nline[5]
    new = l.split(':')
    hour = new[0]

    # Increment count for the hour parsed from line
    counts[hour] = counts.get(hour, 0) + 1
print(counts)
```

---

The last part (to display the hours in order of number of appearances) is an exercise for you.